# Excel Code To Add Values Being Imputed In One Cell

Tags: excel

Is it possible to have one cell where you add in a value and in another cell the values are added together?

For example, I have cell A1 where I put the value 10, then cell B1 is now 10. Then Cell A1 is now blank so that when i add another value, lets say 5, cell B1 would now be 10+5, so 15. Then allow this to continue to repeat and sum the values being added to A1

Comment: You could research the `Worksheet_Change` event.